# How to add a running to Redis?

Tags: database, redis, redis-cluster

From several servers I would like to add keys like doc:1 and then doc:2 etc.

Now in order that the different servers do not try to add to, say, doc:2 at the same time, I thought there is some mechanism like "add to doc:{index}" and the index gets automatically bumped.

Is there some way to make that work?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a distributed lock and have the winner write

```
for each server, attempt to acquire lock until success
on acquire lock
  read numeric value
  increment
  write
  release lock
```

docs

- https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/distributed-locks/
- https://redis.io/commands/incr/

Comment: Many thanks for your input. Would it also be possible to use a list instead? However, one concern is that the maximum size of all items in that list combined is 512 MB or something or can we go beyond that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a key which you increment on every addition: the `INCR` command does just that, atomically, and returns the incremented value which you can use to generate the new key name.

```
> INCR counter
42

> SET doc:42 foobar
OK
```

---

**Update**: in the event you want the whole set of operations (incrementing the counter and setting the value) to be atomic, you can execute a Lua script instead:

```
> EVAL "local value = redis.call('INCR', 'counter'); redis.call('SET', 'doc:'..value, ARGV[1])" 0 foobar
(nil)
```

Explanation:

```lua
local value = redis.call('INCR', 'counter');
```

Execute `INCR counter` and store the result in the `value` variable.

```lua
redis.call('SET', 'doc:'..value, ARGV[1]);
```

Execute `SET` against the key named after the concatenation of `doc:` and the `value` variable using the data passed through the first `EVAL` argument - in our case *foobar*.

Finally, should you need to return the incremented counter value to the caller just append a final `return value;` block to the script.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. If I see it correctly, there cannot be a race condition, right?

Comment: However, it could be that we are having some gaps. Assume that a client increases the counter and before inserting something, the client crashes. Then comes the next increase by another client. Isn't there a way to make it more like a transaction?

Comment: @tobias you are welcome: I have updated the answer to reflect the requirement of avoiding gaps. And no, there cannot be race conditions.